# Javascript timer and footer div

Tags: javascript, css, html, timer

I positioned a div to the footer of the page and want it to be made visible when the button is clicked. It doesn't seem to be working. What am i doing wrong? Code is below.

```
<script language="text/javascript">

function timedMsg()
{
var t=setTimeout('ff()',3000)
}

function ff(){

document.getElementById("dot").style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById("dot").style.display="";

}

</script>

<div id="dot" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; margin-right:50px; background-color:blue; width:250px; text-align:center; display: none; visibility: hidden">Footer</div>


<form>
<input type="button" value="Display!" onclick="timedMsg()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ridiculously vague question. What does "it doesn't seem to be working" mean for you? What is the expected behaviour, and how does it differ from the behaviour that you desire? What steps did you attempt so far? Where is the HTML?

Comment: This is a question and please if you do not have an answer, don't post!

Comment: I see that you have now added actual code. The inline CSS overrides the changes you make in your Javascript. Use classes instead. Your div should start with a class that makes it hidden, and then you can remove that in your Javascript with the `.className` property.

Comment: @sammville: On stackoverflow, there are "comment" fields for questions and answers. My response was a "comment", not an "answer", and it was absolutely appropriate. It's best not to be rude when you're asking people for free help.

Comment: Also note that the issue may well be limited to one or more specific user-agents; of course, no user-agent was specified in the problem description, so the best that anyone can do is to guess.

Comment: @Tomalak - Sorry for been rude. I am using chrome to test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all to embed javascript into html page you should use the following syntax:

```
<scrpt type="text/javascript">/* code here */</script>
```

Note: `type`, not `language`!

Second, why do you use the `t` variable? What is it for?

So the working and more complete example would be:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function timedMsg()
            {
                setTimeout('ff()',3000)
            }

            function ff()
            {
                document.getElementById("dot").style.visibility="visible";
                document.getElementById("dot").style.display="";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" value="Display!" onclick="timedMsg()" />
        </form>
        <div id="dot" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; margin-right:50px; background-color:blue; width:250px; text-align:center; display: block; visibility: hidden">Footer
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah!! it was the language.. Stupid omission by me.